# Making a JTable have undo functions using the Netbeans Platform

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-platform

I have a JTable where a user can create a custom report. They can add/remove "rows" which are columns in the report.

I want to have them be able to "undo" a row deletion. Currently they can just reset the whole report back to the standard report via a button. This is OK, but there's a lot of columns and some users are grumbling about the time they can lose if they accidentally delete a row.

I figure I can create a stack easily enough that tracks the rows deleted, so it'll just be a "add" event that I can call on a key event listener (listen for ctrl-z, or a button perhaps). Once it's called, it'll just pop off the stack and add the row.

But, since I'm using the Netbeans platform anyway, I'd love to tie into the edit->undo functionality that exists there.

What are the commands, or API calls that I can make to tie into that undo functionality that exists in the platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add an action to your application (using the wizard).

Maybe this comes handy:

1. Related issue: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=204828
2. Related tutorial: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/enabling_undo_redo_functionality_on
3. You can also just add it as a right click menu to the table itself: [JTable Right-Click popupmenu in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241537/jtable-right-click-popupmenu-in-netbeans)